# Rails 4 Partial with Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, ruby-on-rails-4

I am doing something obviously wrong here, but I don't get it.

I have a partial call like so:

```
= render 'shared/purchase', collection: @purchases
```

`@purchases` is defined in the controller like so:

```
@purchases = current_user.purchases
```

But I get this error:

```
app/views/shared/_purchase.html.slim where line #3 raised:

undefined local variable or method `purchase' for #<<Class:0x007fd8ca54f970>:0x007fd8ca54eb60>
```

However, when I change the partial to just render the local_assigns I see this:

```
[:collection, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Purchase id: 40, user_id: 20, purchaseable_id: 6, purchaseable_type: "PurchaseType", frequency: "Weekly", day: "Su", notes: "leave at gate", allergies: "peanuts", created_at: "2013-07-24 16:58:08", updated_at: "2013-07-24 16:58:08", size: "Normal", quantity: 2>, #<Purchase id: 41, user_id: 20, purchaseable_id: 5, purchaseable_type: "PurchaseType", frequency: "Weekly", day: "Su", notes: "leave at gate", allergies: "peanuts", created_at: "2013-07-24 16:58:08", updated_at: "2013-07-24 16:58:08", size: "Jumbo", quantity: 3>, #<Purchase id: 42, user_id: 20, purchaseable_id: 7, purchaseable_type: "PurchaseType", frequency: "Weekly", day: "Su", notes: "leave at gate", allergies: "peanuts", created_at: "2013-07-24 16:58:08", updated_at: "2013-07-24 16:58:08", size: nil, quantity: 1>, #<Purchase id: 43, user_id: 20, purchaseable_id: 8, purchaseable_type: "PurchaseType", frequency: "Weekly", day: "Su", notes: "leave at gate", allergies: "peanuts", created_at: "2013-07-24 16:58:08", updated_at: "2013-07-24 16:58:08", size: nil, quantity: 1>]>]
[:purchase, nil]
```

Why isn't each collection item getting picked up as the local variable `purchase`?

I'm tearing my hair out, I'm sure it's something stupid, I've done this many times before, and even compared old working code to this and I can't figure out what the problem is. Either it's a new Rails 4 thing that I'm not seeing in the docs, or I'm an idiot.

Thanks!

Comment: The [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) gives an example using the `partial` parameter for `render` (`<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products %>`). I'm not sure if this will make a difference but it's worth a try.

Comment: @KyleDecot yep that's totally it. What a dumb mistake. If you answer if i'll give you the credit for it.

Comment: Not dumb at all. I would expect that to work as well.

Comment: Just spent way too much time struggling with this same issue!  Thank you Kyle Decot!

Comment: haha same - was driving me nuts as I thought I'd followed the documentation to a "T"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Rails documentation on [Layouts and Render in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) gives an example using the `partial` parameter for `render`:

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products %>
```